# PHP parser converter for a Tcl dictionary to JSON or ARRAY

Tags: php, regex, dictionary, parsing, tcl

After really long research, no solution was found.
So stackoverflow is my last hope.

In PHP I need a parser for data getting from a postgreSQL DB.

The string construct is like:

```
"keytext {this is my value text 1} key with multi words {value text 2} another key {key_value number 3}"
```

So we have the key (could consist of several words) and the value in curly braces.

I think, this data type comes from TCL.

How can we convert this string to a JSON-String or an array in PHP 7/8 ??

THANK you VERY MUCH FOR trying to help me!.

**UPDATE:**

Oh dear,
I've found a second condition, which makes it much more complicated to convert the TCL dict to a JSON Format:

```
user_receiver {all} manifest 3200 transferCode {B45}  time hours 0 status {1a} local {} is online {}
```

As you can see, there are number values in the string, which aren't hold in curly braces.

-> string values are in curly braces

-> number values are not

So, does anybody know, how to use REGEX to anything else, to get the key value pairs?

Comment: That looks a bit unlikely. `keytext {this is my value text 1} {key with multi words} {value text 2} {another key} {key_value number 3}` would be the expected version…

Comment: How should the expected output ("JSON string"?) look like?

Comment: It's a TCL dictionary format and it should be converted to standard json.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a perfect way but it's work.

```
$string = "keytext {this is my value text 1} key with multi words {value text 2} another key {key_value number 3}";

$results = explode('{', $string);
$newArray = $values = [];
 
foreach ($results as $result){
    if (strpos($result, '}') !== false) {
        $values[] = explode('}', $result)[0];
        $keys[] = explode('}', $result)[1];
    } else {
        $keys[] = $result;
    }
}

$newArray = [];

foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
    if ($key !== '' && isset($values[$index])){
        $newArray[$key] = $values[$index];
    }
}
return $newArray;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: Ok, as I have tested it - it seems to work. But I cannot say 100% it will work reliable, because of weird things like curly braces in value etc. could make trouble. Same for special chars.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
$str = "keytext {this is my value text 1} key with multi words {value text 2} another key {key_value number 3}";
$chars = str_split($str);

$result_arr = [];
$make_arr_key = true;
$make_arr_key_val = false;
$arr_key = '';
$arr_key_val = '';
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    if($char == '{') {
        $make_arr_key = false;
        $arr_key_val = '';
        $make_arr_key_val = true;
    }

    if($char == '}') {
        $result_arr[trim($arr_key)] = trim($arr_key_val);
        $arr_key = '';
        $make_arr_key = true;
        $make_arr_key_val = false;
    }

    if($make_arr_key) {
        if($char != '}'){
            $arr_key .= $char;
        }
    }

    if($make_arr_key_val) {
        if($char != '{') {
            $arr_key_val .= $char;
        }
    }

}
print_r($result_arr);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. Hopefully a reliable version.